# Show an image on form submit if an error occurs

Tags: javascript, php

On my website I need that form to upload an image and i made this  function using javascript to show that image live after selected. I'm doing validation for all the fields on the form.

My problem is my image is disappearing when i click submit but my others fields take the value user entered it self. please help me to keep  this value weather error or not.

javascript

```
 function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
};
```

html

```
<img alt="Not selected" id="uploadPreview"  style="width: 200px; height: 180px;" />
<input id="uploadImage" value="<?php echo $pht1; ?>" type="file" name="pht1" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
```

Comment: maybe you made alitlle too smart

Comment: It is posible.
Look at this website. this website do it.Try to add a photo and submit the post.It will return back because other fields keep empty.But photo is still displaying [http://ikman.lk/en/post-ad/details

Comment: Okay, you will probably notice that is not a normal file input. The way that one works is to upload the image with AJAX when it is selected, return an image ID and submit that image ID when submitting the form. If the form has errors then the image that has already been uploaded is used again. You will notice that what they don't do is reset the file upload field to point to the same file again.

Comment: yes.  I want to do the same thing .
I want to show the image when form return errors.But i dont want that file to be uploaded until no errors

Comment: Well then again I must say that's impossible. The example you've posted specifically works by uploading the file before the form is checked for errors.

Comment: ok.Do you have any suggestions for this ?

Comment: Use AJAX to upload the file, as I said in my first comment. If the form is not successfully submitted after a fixed amount of time (say 24 hours), delete the uploaded image.

Comment: im stuck at ajax codes.Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: but are you sure this form is going to insert this only on one record in the database ?

Comment: The example form you have linked? No it almost certainly uses multiple database records to keep track of when to delete unused images.

Comment: so . in the first of form submiting i have to keep this dats in a temporary database table and then i have to move it into rthe right table i want to insert ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the standard way of doing it.

Comment: ok.Can you please to me how to use ajax to upload the image ? can you teach me this please ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. For security reasons you cannot pre-set the `value` of a `file` field. Your best bet would be to add some client-side validation for the file field so the form cannot be submitted until it is correct.

Comment: The <pre> tag has nothing to do with @Chris's answer. Also why in the world would you use Java with PHP? use Java/JSP or just PHP.

Comment: @anandavanderwall I'm not referring to `pre` tags. I am saying that the `value` attribute of a field with `type="file"` will be ignored. This is to prevent malicious websites from uploading files the user did not choose themselves.

Comment: Thank you everyone, but here is what i want.

I want to keep my photo in that image tag weather im returning a erro on submit as other text fields and text areas keeps their values

Comment: @anandavanderwall And as I have said, that is not possible. It cannot be done. No browser will allow it.